# email sending throgh java program gets "Network is unreachable"

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

Here is my code:

```
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SendEmailutil {
    // private  static String SMTP_SERVER;
    private static final String USERNAME = "shabbbirahmadz1996@gmail.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "shabbir1996";
    private static final String EMAIL_FROM = "shabbbirahmadz1996@gmail.com";
    private static final String EMAIL_TO = "shabbbirahmadz888@gmail.com";
    private static final String EMAIL_TO_CC = "";
    private static final String EMAIL_SUBJECT = "Test Send Email via SMTP";
    private static final String EMAIL_TEXT = "Hello Java Mail \n ABC123";

    public static void sendmail() {
        Properties prop = System.getProperties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "587"); //optional, defined in SMTPTransport
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); // default port 25

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, null);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            // from
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM));
            // to 
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(EMAIL_TO, true));
            // cc
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                InternetAddress.parse(EMAIL_TO_CC, true));
            // subject
            msg.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT);
            // content 
            msg.setText(EMAIL_TEXT);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            // Get SMTPTransport
            SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");
            // connect
            t.connect(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            // send
            t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Response: " + t.getLastServerResponse());
            t.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 587, 25; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
at 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please give more details on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: i just want to send email using java code

Comment: The reason is right there in the error stack trace: "Network is unreachable". This is because you set the host name to "587", which is not a fully qualified domain name. You probably want `smtp.gmail.com` instead.

Comment: See the [Gmail instructions in the JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).